# DB2/400 SQL : FullText

Tags: sql, full-text-search, db2-400, full-text-indexing

SQL DB2/400 : Is there somebody has tried to work wth FullText.

If i can have a sql exemple code, it will be great .

I would like, for exemple,  to use it with a clob column.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *FullText*?  I'm not sure DB2/400 even had full text searching... DB2 for i5  I believe introduced *DB2 Text Extender* which supported full text searches.   *Db2 OmniFind* replaced those in v6(?) of IBM i and is the product supported on the latest release (v7.3) of the platform formerly know as AS/400.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?  Can you provide sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This pulls out all of space delimited words from mylib.myfile[mytext]**
and puts them into a table with two columns.  I limit the word length to 15 cause really when do users type in words longer than 15 chars anyways and I've probably already found a match on the 1st 15 and presented a list to the user.

*I copied this technique off the interweb.*

```
CREATE TABLE mylib.myidx AS
(                                   
  WITH SPLITTER (ID, START, E, SECTION, ORIGINAL, NUM) AS 
  ( SELECT UID, 1, LOCATE(' ', mytext), CAST('' AS VARCHAR(8000)), mytext, 0  
      FROM mylib/myfile                                               
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, E + 1,
           CASE WHEN LOCATE(' ',ORIGINAL, E + 1) > 0
                THEN LOCATE(' ', ORIGINAL, E + 1)
                ELSE LENGTH(ORIGINAL) + 1
             END,
           SUBSTRING(ORIGINAL, START, E - START), 
           ORIGINAL, NUM + 1
      FROM SPLITTER
      WHERE E > START
  )                 
  SELECT ID AS UID                                                 
        ,CAST(SECTION AS VARCHAR(15)) AS SECTION                         
    FROM SPLITTER
    WHERE LENGTH(SECTION)>1                                 
)
WITH DATA;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I don’t understand this syntax. « Splitter » is a SQL key word ?  I understand you create an index on a physical table.  Is it possible to use this technique on clob column ?  Many thanks for your help !

Comment: The first select uninion back on itself to the end of the first word and so on.

Comment: @JchristopheCherid SPLITTER will be found defined at the top of the answer sql.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer
Can someone tell me if "OmniFind Text Search Server for DB2 for i" is free, or we have to pay for this ?

Comment: Hi 
@danny117 I'm playing with your SQL request and it's very top.  Do you think there is a way to update automatically  your "mylib.myidx" everi time a new record is added in "mylib/myfile" ? Many thanks for help !

Comment: Hi, Can someone explain SQL key word "SECTION" and "START"  ? Thanks !

Comment: Section is column name of output.

Comment: Re START, look at the definition of SPLITTER at the top, you will see it as a column there (along with SECTION).

Comment: "Splitter" is a name being assigned to the [common table expression](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcomtexp.htm) following "AS". "(ID, START, E, SECTION, ORIGINAL, NUM)" are names assigned to the result fields of the common table expression (or CTE).  You might think of a CTE as a temporary intermediate workfile, at least in theory.  The body of a CTE is a [fullselect](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzmark.htm) which is a UNION of [subselects](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzsubselect.htm)